# How can we create interactive 3d 360 degree Gallery in android?

Tags: android, gallery, 360-degrees

I would like to create 3d 360 degree Gallery in android which would be responsive to the user touch,it is to represent cars in the gallery.While the users touch certain parts of  it,planned to add pop with a drop down menu.How can I get this,any expertise on this would be greatly helpful.

Comment: No downvote. What have you tried..?

Comment: This sounds to me like requirements, not really a problem. What have you tried? Do you have some code written? Research done? Anything? Please read [ask].

Comment: I have tried using jquery product viewer in a web view, but I would like to get response values from the user inside the app itself so I turn into this of making into 3d model but there to lies there the same constraint.So I am looking into a different approach for it.How have I to move long from here.